# CasperJS doesn't seem to send all my POST requests

Tags: ajax, apache, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

We are writing an automated test-suite to test forms on our live sites. But it appears that - at random - sometimes these tests fail while the forms are still working. The forms are submitted with AJAX and I use the `waitForResource`-function to wait for the AJAX-response.

Diving deeper in the problem I discovered that CasperJS ís sending the POST-requests (I do this by analysing the `resource.requested`-event, but sometimes this results in the following error (`resource.error`):

```
errorCode: 205
errorString: Unknown error
```

Diving even deeper in the problem, when I look at to apache access logs of the website in question, I notice that when a test succeeds the POST-request is nicely logged (as expected). But... when I get the error as described above, I can find no such entry. It looks like my request never received the server at all! Even though CasperJS's `resource.requested`-event made it clear a POST was sent.

Does anyone else experienced this problem or might know what's going on here? Or even better: how to fix this?

Comment: Interesting ... Does the same error occur with [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/) (you can use it as a casperjs `--engine=`)? What do you see in wireshark? Does it log the request, but not the response?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use some kind of network sniffer to really find out if the requests are leaving Casper/Phantom? (And I'd echo Artjom's suggestion to also try with Slimer, though if it works with Slimer it doesn't necessarily mean the problem is in Phantom.)

Also there is (or used to be - logging changed between Apache 2.2 and 2.4) a way to get more detailed logging in Apache, that should show server-side crashes.

It seems strange for Casper to be generating a 205 error, by itself. It seems much more likely it is something server-side. (Or if there is a reverse proxy in front of Apache, that would be your prime candidate.)

A couple of links to get you started, if you are on Linux:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/packet-sniffing-basics
- https://superuser.com/questions/23180/whats-the-easiest-way-to-sniff-tcp-traffic-data-on-linux